# WPF UI Not updating from ViewModel / Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I have a caliburn Micro application, in which I'm loading several data tables in the bootstrapper.
I'm injecting this into MEF for use later in the application.

I want to show the user with a splash screen of the progress. This is all working fine so far.
I'm using the EventAggregator to have the individual classes throw messages to the Splash Screen ViewModel, however the UI thread seems not the working to update my text label. My property is set fine, and i'm calling the NotifyOfPropertyChange, however my window seems to be frozen, the get ancestor on my bound property is not being called.

```
public string Message
    {
        get
        {
            return this.message;
        }
        set
        {
            this.message = value;
            //new System.Action(() => NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Message)).BeginOnUIThread();
            //App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => NotifyOfPropertyChange("Message"));
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Message);
        }
    }


    public void Handle(StartupNotification message)
    {
        Message = message.Message;
    }
```

The Handle comes from the Caliburn.Micro IHandle EventAggregrator. The data is loaded in the bootstrapper, I assume this thread is seperate from the UI Thread, but i'm not personally creating any threads.

In my bootstrapper I load as follows:

```
events.Publish(new StartupNotification("Loading Feeds..."));
batch.AddExportedValue<IFeedService>(new FeedService());
```

I have tried to trigger the UI by indirect measures, but for some reason my main screen stays frozen.
Can anyone indicate what I'm doing wrong?

Best Regards,
Martin

Comment: Show more code. How is Message being set? How is the binding setup in your view

Comment: Do you load your data in separate thread?

Comment: Is your `Handle` method being called?

Comment: Yes, the Handle is being called, however the binding calls the GET method only at creation of the window and not after any NotifyOnPropertyChange calls.

Comment: Just for a punt, have you tried testing `NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Message);` in the Handle method?

Comment: Does it resolve ?  Should we use "_eventAggregator.PublishOnUIThread" ? Honestly, I want to switch , decide UI or Not UI thread in IHandle Instead of in Publishing time.  I think , This is not good system.. Am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrapper runs in the UI thread, I assume you have soemthing like this:

```
 protected override void OnStartup(object sender, System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e)
 {
     DisplayRootViewFor<ShellViewModel>();
     RunLongLoadingOperation();
 }
```

You should do something like

```
 protected override void OnStartup(object sender, System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e)
 {
     DisplayRootViewFor<ShellViewModel>();
     var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(RunLongLoadingOperation);

     // task error handling omitted, 
     // if your long operation can throw an exception you should 
     // add an oncompleted handler and do something with it or the
     // app will be brought down when the task gets GC'd
 }
```

Comment: The problem is that several ViewModels in the main model are injected with the data that I try to load in my splash screen. That is why I have been loading this in my main loop.

Comment: The strategy I normally use there is to have the last item in the splash screen loading process do some sort of "LoadMainView()" so that everything is all done and dusted in the background thread before you start moving along

Comment: I'm doing the same thing, now in my main thread, but the UI still does not update.              Message = "Loading Feeds...";
            IoC.Get<IFeedService>().LoadItems();

Comment: This get's really confusing, i'm running all in the same thread now, nicely calling the NotifyOfPropertyChange() method, however I can also see that View is frozen when I run the code. I've moved all into a Task.Factory.StartNew() however, i have the same behaviour. How about a VB.NET DoEvents()?

Answer (score -3):

This is now solved, I have moved my DB loads into a background worker, and added Thread.Sleep in there to allow some time for the UI to update on the ProgressChanged events.

I expected .NET to take care of this since I moved it to a background worker already, but oh well.